# Goroutines, Callbacks and sync.WaitGroup

Tags: go, callback, goroutine

With the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "sync"
    "time"
)
func callbackWithTimeout(cbFunc func() ([]byte, error), timeout time.Duration) {
    defer wg.Done() //I don't want this function to know about sync.WaitGroup
    time.Sleep(timeout)
    d, e := cbFunc()
    spew.Dump(d)
    spew.Dump(e)
}
var wg sync.WaitGroup
func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        cbFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
            //I feel like I should be able to defer here instead
            return nil, nil
        }
        callbackWithTimeout(cbFunc, time.Duration(4*time.Second))
    }()
    println("some line")
    wg.Wait()
}
```

In function `callbackWithTimeout`, I don't want to use `defer wg.Done()` because it's not `callbackWithTimeout()`'s concern to `wg.Done()`. How do I go about implementing such a thing? i.e., remove any `sync.WaitGroup` in `callbackWithTimeout`? I have a bit of problem understanding the separation of concerns here as a callback'er function should not have to know about waitgroups but in this case it seems, I have no other choice?

*I feel like it should be a caller's responsibility* to `wg.Done()` (which in this case is the `cbFunc`) but lack any concise reference to documentation or ideas on how to implement it in Go because by definition, all a callback function does is call the function back. So, where I am doing it wrong?

---

Silly assumptions were made by yours truly during refactoring. Working code below. Many thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func callbackWithTimeout(cbFunc func() ([]byte, error), timeout time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(timeout)
    d, e := cbFunc()
    spew.Dump(d)
    spew.Dump(e)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        callbackWithTimeout(func() ([]byte, error) {
            b := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4}
            e := errors.New("error123")
            return b, e
        }, time.Duration(2*time.Second))
    }()
    println("some line")
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Why no just  go func() {  defer wg.Done()

Comment: this is absolutely nuts. Thank you.. Silly mistake on my part. My original code had `go func() { defer wg.Done() .......` but in the middle of refactoring, i made some silly assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this?

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func callbackWithTimeout(cbFunc func() ([]byte, error), timeout time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(timeout)
    d, e := cbFunc()
    spew.Dump(d)
    spew.Dump(e)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done() // move it here
        cbFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
            //I feel like I should be able to defer here instead
            return nil, nil
        }
        callbackWithTimeout(cbFunc, time.Duration(4*time.Second))
    }()

    println("some line")

    wg.Wait()
}
```